# the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, spring, servlets

every one .

here is my piece of code i have checked many links of stack overflow butt error still remains.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean id = "HandlerMapping" class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
<bean name = "/welcome.html" class= "com.FirstProject.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>
<bean id= "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name = "prefix" >  </property>
    <value>WEB-INF</value>
    <property name= "suffix">  </property>
    <value>.JSP </value>
</bean>
```

Comment: You have three root elements, thus a malformed XML document.

Comment: Three, if I'm counting correctly.

Comment: @pointy got me! Just noticed haha

Comment: how can i resolve this..help me any one

Comment: Go look at any valid `beans.xml` and the issues with yours should become apparentl pretty quickly. You need to wrap your document in a `<beans . . .>. . .</beans>` tag and fix the nesting of your `<property>` and `<value>` tags.

Comment: i am new here can you give some more explanation..please.

Answer (score 1):

The root element of an XML document must wrap all other elements. In your XML you have 3  elements which open and close without any parents. You should wrap these in a  element, or something of the like.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans>
        <bean id = "HandlerMapping" class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
        <bean name = "/welcome.html" class= "com.FirstProject.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>
        <bean id= "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
            <property name = "prefix" >  </property>
            <value>WEB-INF</value>
            <property name= "suffix">  </property>
            <value>.JSP </value>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```